# how to add text in center of donut chart?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I tried a lot but not getting where to place string so that I get text in the center.

this is the code.
'in this I get value and color from another class and call "addItem"
where should I edit so I get text in center.

This is the chart image:

[image]

```
public class PieDonutChart extends ViewGroup {

private List<Item> mData = new ArrayList<Item>();
private int mTotal = 0;

private RectF mPieBounds = new RectF();

private Paint mPiePaint;
private Paint mCirclePaint;

private PieView mPieView;
private CircleView mCircleView;

private float mRatioCircleInside = 0.5f;
private int mColorCircleInside;
private float mHighlightStrength = 1.15f;
private int mPieRotation;

/**
 * Class constructor taking only a context. Use this constructor to create
 * {@link PieDonutChart} objects from your own code.
 *
 * @param context
 */
public PieDonutChart(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

/**
 * Class constructor taking a context and an attribute set. This constructor
 * is used by the layout engine to construct a {@link PieDonutChart} from a set of
 * XML attributes.
 *
 * @param context
 * @param attrs   An attribute set which can contain attributes from
 *                {@link com.PieDonutChart.chartdemo.charting.R.styleable.PieChart} as well as attributes inherited
 *                from {@link android.view.View}.
 */
public PieDonutChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    // attrs contains the raw values for the XML attributes
    // that were specified in the layout, which don't include
    // attributes set by styles or themes, and which may have
    // unresolved references. Call obtainStyledAttributes()
    // to get the final values for each attribute.
    //
    // This call uses R.styleable.PieChart, which is an array of
    // the custom attributes that were declared in attrs.xml.
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.PieDonutChart,
            0, 0
    );

    try {
        // Retrieve the values from the TypedArray and store into
        // fields of this class.
        //
        // The R.styleable.PieChart_* constants represent the index for
        // each custom attribute in the R.styleable.PieChart array.
        mHighlightStrength = a.getFloat(R.styleable.PieDonutChart_highlightStrength, 1.0f);
        mRatioCircleInside = a.getFloat(R.styleable.PieDonutChart_ratioCircleInside, 0.0f);
        mColorCircleInside = a.getColor(R.styleable.PieDonutChart_colorCircleInside, 0xffffffff);
        mPieRotation = a.getInt(R.styleable.PieDonutChart_pieRotation, 0);
    } finally {
        // release the TypedArray so that it can be reused.
        a.recycle();
    }

    init();
}

/**
 * Add a new data item to this view. Adding an item adds a slice to the pie whose
 * size is proportional to the item's value. As new items are added, the size of each
 * existing slice is recalculated so that the proportions remain correct.
 *
 * @param value The value of this item.
 * @param color The ARGB color of the pie slice associated with this item.
 * @return The index of the newly added item.
 */
public int addItem(int value, int color) {
    Item it = new Item();
    it.mColor = color;
    it.mValue = value;

    // Calculate the highlight color. Saturate at 0xff to make sure that high values
    // don't result in aliasing.
    it.mHighlight = Color.argb(
            0xff,
            Math.min((int) (mHighlightStrength * (float) Color.red(color)), 0xff),
            Math.min((int) (mHighlightStrength * (float) Color.green(color)), 0xff),
            Math.min((int) (mHighlightStrength * (float) Color.blue(color)), 0xff)
    );
    mTotal += value;

    mData.add(it);

    //onDataChanged();

    return mData.size() - 1;
}

public void deleteItems() {
    mTotal = 0;
    mData.clear();
}



@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
}






@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    //
    // Set dimensions for pie chart
    //
    // Account for padding
    float xpad = (float) (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
    float ypad = (float) (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());

    // Account for the view
    float ww = (float) w - xpad;
    float hh = (float) h - ypad;

    // Figure out how big we can make the pie (it's a square).
    float diameter = Math.min(ww, hh);
    mPieBounds = new RectF(
            0.0f,
            0.0f,
            diameter,
            diameter);
    mPieBounds.offsetTo(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());

    // Lay out the child view that actually draws the pie.
    mPieView.layout((int) mPieBounds.left,
            (int) mPieBounds.top,
            (int) mPieBounds.right,
            (int) mPieBounds.bottom);
    mPieView.setPivot(mPieBounds.width() / 2, mPieBounds.height() / 2);

    mCircleView.layout((int) mPieBounds.left,
            (int) mPieBounds.top,
            (int) mPieBounds.right,
            (int) mPieBounds.bottom);        

    onDataChanged();
}
/**
 * Do all of the recalculations needed when the data array changes.
 */
private void onDataChanged() {
    // When the data changes, we have to recalculate
    // all of the angles.
    int currentAngle = 0;
    for (Item it : mData) {
        it.mStartAngle = currentAngle;

        // BL : mini hack for having the last item to close the pie
        if(it.equals(mData.get(mData.size()-1))) {
            it.mEndAngle = 360;
        } else {
            it.mEndAngle = currentAngle + it.mValue * 360 / mTotal;
        }
        currentAngle = it.mEndAngle;


        // Recalculate the gradient shaders. There are
        // three values in this gradient, even though only
        // two are necessary, in order to work around
        // a bug in certain versions of the graphics engine
        // that expects at least three values if the
        // positions array is non-null.
        //
        it.mShader = new SweepGradient(
                mPieBounds.width() / 2.0f,
                mPieBounds.height() / 2.0f,
                new int[]{
                        it.mHighlight,
                        it.mHighlight,
                        it.mColor,
                        it.mColor,
                },
                new float[]{
                        0,
                        (float) (360 - it.mEndAngle) / 360.0f,
                        (float) (360 - it.mStartAngle) / 360.0f,
                        1.0f
                }
        );
    }
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        invalidate();
    }
    mPieView.decelerate();
}

/**
 * Initialize the control. This code is in a separate method so that it can be
 * called from both constructors.
 */
private void init() {
    // Force the background to software rendering because otherwise the Blur
    // filter won't work.
    setLayerToSW(this);

    // Set up the paint for the circle 
    mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mCirclePaint.setColor(mColorCircleInside);

    // Set up the paint for the pie slices
    mPiePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPiePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    // Add a child view to draw the pie. Putting this in a child view
    // makes it possible to draw it on a separate hardware layer that rotates
    // independently
    mPieView = new PieView(getContext());
    addView(mPieView);
    mPieView.rotateTo(mPieRotation);

    // The circle doesn't need hardware acceleration, but in order to show up
    // in front of the pie it also needs to be on a separate view.
    mCircleView = new CircleView(getContext());
    addView(mCircleView);

    // In edit mode it's nice to have some demo data, so add that here.
    if (this.isInEditMode()) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        addItem(3, res.getColor(R.color.holo_blue_light));
        addItem(4, res.getColor(R.color.holo_green_light));
        addItem(2, res.getColor(R.color.holo_red_light));
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
private void setLayerToSW(View v) {
    if (!v.isInEditMode() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
}

/**
 * Internal child class that draws the pie chart onto a separate hardware layer
 * when necessary.
 */
private class PieView extends View {
    // Used for SDK < 11
    private float mRotation = 0;
    private Matrix mTransform = new Matrix();
    private PointF mPivot = new PointF();
    private RectF mBounds;

    /**
     * Construct a PieView
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public PieView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Disable hardware acceleration (releases memory)
     */
    public void decelerate() {
        setLayerToSW(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            mTransform.set(canvas.getMatrix());
            mTransform.preRotate(mRotation, mPivot.x, mPivot.y);
            canvas.setMatrix(mTransform);
        }

        for (Item it : mData) {
            mPiePaint.setShader(it.mShader);
            canvas.drawArc(mBounds,
                    360 - it.mEndAngle,
                    it.mEndAngle - it.mStartAngle,
                    true, mPiePaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mBounds = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    public void rotateTo(float pieRotation) {
        mRotation = pieRotation;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            setRotation(pieRotation);
        } else {
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    public void setPivot(float x, float y) {
        mPivot.x = x;
        mPivot.y = y;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            setPivotX(x);
            setPivotY(y);
        } else {
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Maintains the state for a data item.
 */
private class Item {
    public int mValue;
    public int mColor;

    // computed values
    public int mStartAngle;
    public int mEndAngle;

    public int mHighlight;
    public Shader mShader;
}

/**
 * View that draws the white circle on top of the pie chart
 */
private class CircleView extends View {
    private RectF mBounds;

    /**
     * Construct a PointerView object
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawCircle(mBounds.centerX(), mBounds.centerY(), mBounds.width() *0.5f * mRatioCircleInside, mCirclePaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mBounds = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you have values, you have widgets, you have container layouts. why not use them wisely. using textview, your piechart and frame layout would be a good choice

Comment: @KaranMer   Sir please tell me where to place textview I have no idea.

Comment: take one frame layout and place your textview and piechart in it. set `android:gravity="center"` for frame layout. and run your code.